# AppleScript error/no result when clicking FaceTime Accept button in Notification Center

Tags: applescript, notifications, facetime, ventura

### Background:

I want to automatically answer incoming FaceTime calls on a dedicated Mac without user interaction. Since the hidden FaceTime `defaults write com.Apple.FaceTime` `AutoAcceptInvites` (a boolean) and `AutoAcceptInvitesFrom` (email or phone or contact card name) no longer work* (and indeed may not have worked in a great *many* OS versions), I tried a kludgy UI scripting way to accept an incoming FT call. This is on Ventura 13.1.

*I ran `strings` on the FaceTime binary and didn't see anything promising, but if anyone knows of an easier, `defaults`-based way of doing this, I'm all ears.

### The button I want to click: "Accept"

[image: The first button, "Accept"]

### What I tried:

I got the hierarchy of the Notification Center via Accessibility Inspector:
[image: Here's the hierarchy]

I then wrote an AppleScript to try to find that button and click it. It errors out with

> System Events got an error: Can’t get window 1 of application process "NotificationCenter". Invalid index.

if the Notification Center isn't visible. When I place a FT call to the computer and the Notification Center IS visible, it runs, but doesn't do anything, which tells me that the syntax is valid but the logic is wrong.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell its application process "NotificationCenter"
        tell its window 1
            --          tell its group 1
            --              tell its scroll area 1
            set btns to its buttons
            repeat with btn in btns
                if name of btn = "accept" then
                    click btn
                end if
            end repeat
            --              end tell
            --          end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

(I commented out the group and scroll area checks here, in the hopes that they weren't necessary. I tried it with them, too, but it also did nothing.

I also tried a much simpler approach:
`if button "Accept" of scroll area 1 of group 1 of window 1 of application process "NotificationCenter" exists then click button "Accept" of scroll area 1 of group 1 of window 1 of application process "NotificationCenter"`
but that didn't work so I figured it couldn't be that simple.

Comment: Try to [debug your script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1466314) and report back (with a detailed log output) if it still doesn’t work

Comment: I did try to debug as much as I could. The UI hierarchy helped, but I don't know a good way to enumerate all items in a window or group or scroll area and dump them into a dialog for inspection.